# Does "Ni zai nar? Ni zuo shenme?" correctly express "Where are you? What are you doing?"

Tags: word-choice

> Where are you? What are you doing?

I translated this to:

> Ni zai nar? Ni zuo shenme?

But I found

> Ni zai zuo shenme?

online.  How is it zai zuo (in + to do)? Is it correct if I just say zuo (to do)?? Does it express the right meaning?

Comment: `zai` in "Ni zai nar?" is a preposition, meaning "in; at". `zai+Verb` in "Ni zai zuo shenme?" is an adverb, expressing continuation of an action, in other words: `V-ing`. It's okay to omit `zai` and just say "Ni zuo shenme?"

Comment: 在 refers to *progressive tense* explicitly.

Comment: usually called "progressive aspect" 动作的进行 most recently discussed in https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/30209/using-xi%c3%a0nz%c3%a0i-and-zh%c3%a8ngz%c3%a0i-in-a-single-sentence

Comment: You're all good at grammar. What I want to say is: "zai" can also be "zhengzai"(正在). You may say "Ni zhengzai zuo shenme?", but this would be more formal than "Ni zai zuo shenme?"

Comment: I say Ni zai zuo shenme? only when I want to know what you are doing right now, like when I call someone on the phone and want to know that. The "zai" is actually short for 现在, (Xiàn zài)

Answer (score 2):

We usually don't say "你做什么(ni zuo shen me)". We only say it when we are shocked, like when you just meet a man trying to robber you, you'll say that to him.

If you're asking someone what are you doing, you should use "你在做什么(ni zai zuo shen me)".

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to skin a cat and more than one way to express oneself. Here a couple of suggestions which may fit in certain circumstances. You can listen and read the words.

Listen [here](https://www.xiami.com/play?ids=/song/playlist/id/70728/object_name/default/object_id/0#loaded)(张国荣)
Where are you?
你在何地

Listen [here](http://bd.kuwo.cn/yinyue/891952?from=baidu)
Where are you all now?
你们如今在何方

What are you doing?!

你在干什么？
What are you doing?

What the hell are you doing? （a little angry)
你到底在干吗？

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is perfectly fine:

> Where are you?
> 你在哪儿？
> <sub>Nǐ zài nǎr?</sub>

The usage of 在 (zài) = "to be located at" here is different to its usage in the second part.

With regards to the second sentence, the 在 (zài) indicates an action in progress, in this case it modifies the verb 做 (zuò) = "to do".

> What are you doing?
> 你**在**做什么？
> <sub>Nǐ **zài** zuò shénme?</sub>

I don't believe it's grammatically incorrect without the 在 (zài), but it's ambiguous and unusual.  Typically we would hear it in:

> What's your job?
> 你做什么工作？
> <sub>Nǐ zuò shénme gōngzuò?</sub>
>
> What should I do?
> 我应该做什么?
> <sub>Wǒ yīnggāi zuò shénme?</sub>

---

The distinction may be clearer if we replace 做 (zuò) = "to do" with 吃 (chī) = "to eat".

> What are you eating?
> 你**在**吃什么？
> <sub>Nǐ **zài** chī shénme?</sub>
>
> What do you eat?
> 你吃什么？
> Nǐ chī shénme?

The first question is about what you are currently eating ("I'm currently eating M&M's").  The second question is about what you generally eat ("I eat vegetarian food").

Answer (score 0):

I would add 在 to make 你**在**做什么？

In this case, 在 would make the equivalent of the English present progressive VERB*ing* ending.