# Need help in understanding this question from sample hsk question

Tags: grammar

大家好！ 在hsk我遇到这个句子，终于没看懂。

句子是 ：

而时间是有限的， 所以不但要会读书，而且还要会选择其中的好书阅读。

I am confused upon seeing 要 and 会 together and the overall sentence meaning.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: 而时间是有限的， 所以不但要是读书，而且还要会选择其中的好书阅读
(however) time is limited, therefore you must not only read books, but also be able to choose the good books among them to read ('the books worth reading among them")

要 must, it is necessary, 会 be able to, know how to, can

Comment: @user6065 comments are not for answers, please make your comment an answer.

Comment: too trivial to be called answer, also see comment #5ff of https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/30209/using-xi%c3%a0nz%c3%a0i-and-zh%c3%a8ngz%c3%a0i-in-a-single-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 而时间是有限的， 所以不但要会读书，而且还要会选择其中的好书阅读。

In this context:

要: need;

会: know how (to);

A rough translation:

*Well, time is limited, so we need not only know how to read books but also know how to pick good ones among (all kinds of) books to read.*